# Adding image into background with embedded CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS. I'm wanting to add an image to the background of my page but I do not know how to do that.

I am wanting to keep the CSS internal to the page, so that this background image is specified by the CSS in the `<head>` of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <h2>How to write 'Text' in 6 of coding languages </h2>
</head>
<style>
body {
 background-color: rgb(60, 60, 60);
 }

h2 {
 color: white;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 200%;
 }

h4 {
 color: white;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 165%;
 }

h6 {
 color: white;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 125%;
 }

p {
 color: white;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 100%;
 }
</style>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [background-image](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) CSS property.

Comment: Where specifically do you want the image? The background of which element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an image for the background of your page via the [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) CSS property. Here, a background image is specified via a URL and applied to the `body` element of the document:

```
body {
 background-color: rgb(60, 60, 60);

 /* Add this */
 background-image: url(https://www.vemco.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/image-banner2.jpg);
 }
```

Here is a complete example with your existing HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <h2>How to write 'Text' in 6 of coding languages </h2>
</head>
<style>
body {
 background-color: rgb(60, 60, 60);
 
 /* Add this */
 background-image: url(https://www.vemco.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/image-banner2.jpg);
 }

h2 {
 color: white;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 200%;
 }

h4 {
 color: white;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 165%;
 }

h6 {
 color: white;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 125%;
 }

p {
 color: white;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 100%;
 }
</style>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just wondering, do I need the background color in the code now because I have the image in there?

Comment: You can remove the background color if you want. If you leave it specified though, then that color will be used around the outside of the image if the image doesn't cover the `body` element of your page.

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much. I had a feeling it'd be in the CSS area, but I know CSS even less than HTML, so this has helped me a boat ton by making this project move along.

Comment: You're welcome - glad I could help, PM me anytime you need help again :)

Comment: I will when I get a question!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background` attribute  ,

```
<body background="bgimage.jpg">
```

Using CSS,

```
    body
    {
       background-image: url("bgimage.jpg");
    }
```

You can also use   `background` shorthand property as well which allows you to set different background properties which includes `background-image` as well,

```
body { 
  background: lightblue url("bgimage.jpg") no-repeat fixed center; 
}
```